# How to use Rails include?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, join, activerecord

I have a model user with many orders

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :orders, inverse_of: :user, dependent: restrict_with_exception
end
```

and a model order as follows :-

```
Class Order < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :order
end
```

I want to fetch all orders but with details of user like user.name and user.mobile in same set. How do I use include in this case?

Comment: Your second code is invalid.

Comment: can you try without inverse_of:

Comment: Try `belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :orders`

Comment: Where do you plan to use it? Show some mode code.

Comment: I need to traverse through all order and will have to call order.user.name and user.mobile each time resulting in many db queries. I am thinking of making a join or include user.mobile and user.name column with original orders itself.

Comment: `Order.includes(:user)`?

Comment: What @MarekLipka said or if you would like to collect them all in 1 query `Order.includes(:user).references(:user)` if you are not using `users` in the where clause

Answer (score 1):

You can use includes using the below mentioned query:

```
@users = User.where(id: 1).includes(:orders)
```

then iterate over @users and fetch the corresponding user and order data.

Also, you could use lazy loading as well using the below query:

```
@users = User.where(id: 3).joins(:orders => [:order_data]).select("orders.*, users.first_name")
```

In this you will be getting all the data in the single query without rails caching the db objects in memory  as in the case of includes.