# Rails includes with where condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
end
```

**order.rb**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :orders
end
```

I am using `includes` with `where` like this:

```
User.where(id: selected_salesmen.pluck(:id))
    .includes(:orders)
    .where("order.booked_at > ? AND order.booked_at < ?", 
           booked_at_gteq, 
           booked_at_lteq)
```

However, it's not giving me required `users` with `orders`. Any explanation of why this isn't working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Rails include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323598/how-to-use-rails-include)

Comment: Yes, but booked_at was not there

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No error, but I am not getting desired result. It always gives me  #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x2abcc08>
 something like that and I get nil on using "count" or "all" etc.

Answer (score 1):

This may be some confusing between the methods `includes` and `joins`, which have related, but very different meanings.

- `includes` will eager-load related records, which prevents multiple database calls later on. It's mostly used for performance tuning.
- `joins` will include a join to the related table in your database query, which allows you to build conditions based on the related model.

Note that, to use joins, you need to refer to the table name, not the relation name. By default, ActiveRecord will connect to a table which is the pluralised name of the model.

So, change includes to joins and 'order' to 'orders':

```
User.where(id: selected_salesmen.pluck(:id))
    .joins(:orders)
    .where(
      "orders.booked_at > ? AND orders.booked_at < ?", 
      booked_at_gteq, 
      booked_at_lteq
    )
```

You may also want to check that `selected_salesmen.pluck(:id)` returns some ids, too.